# what does terminal command: ls -l show?

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, ls

I know that it outputs the "long" version but what do each of the sections mean?

On my mac, when I type in

```
ls -l /Users
```

I get

```
total 0
drwxr-xr-x+ 33 MaxHarris  staff  1122 Jul  1 14:06 MaxHarris
drwxrwxrwt   8 root       wheel   272 May 20 13:26 Shared
drwxr-xr-x+ 14 admin      staff   476 May 17 11:25 admin
drwxr-xr-x+ 44 hugger     staff  1496 Mar 17 21:13 hugger
```

I know that the first line it the permissions, although I don't know what the order is. It would be great if that could be explained too. Then whats the number after it?

Basically, what do each one of these things mean? Why are the usernames written twice sometimes and don't match other times?

Comment: `man ls` will tell you

Comment: This is a good resource for those wanting a full explanation on permissions in the context of the `ls -l` command: http://linuxcommand.org/lts0070.php

Comment: In my case `man ls` doesn't mention specific information about each column. It just says *'use a long listing format'* on `-l` flag. (Ubuntu 20.04)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The option '-l' tells the command to use a long list format. It gives back several columns wich correspond to:

- Permissions
- Number of hardlinks
- File owner
- File group
- File size
- Modification time
- Filename

The first letter in the permissions column show the file's type. A 'd' means a directory and a '-' means a normal file (there are other characters, but those are the basic ones).
The next nine characters are divided into 3 groups, each one a permission. Each letter in a group correspond to the read, write and execute permission, and each group correspond to the owner of the file, the group of the file and then for everyone else.

- [ File type ][ Owner permissions ][ Group permissions ][ Everyone permissions ]

The characters can be one of four options:

- r = read permission
- w = write permission
- x = execute permission
- `-` = no permission

Finally, the "+" at the end means some extended permissions.

Comment: The "+" is partly right and means that there's an Access Control List (ACL) in the extended attributes. There can also be the "@" character, which means there are extended attributes, such as apple's quarantine attribute that flags when a file has been downloaded or copied from an external source.

Answer (score 13):

If you type the command

```
$ man ls
```

You’ll get the [documentation for `ls`](https://ss64.com/osx/ls.html), which says in part:

> **The Long Format**
> If the `-l` option is given, the following information is displayed for
> each file: file mode, number of links, owner name, group name, number of
> bytes in the file, abbreviated month, day-of-month file was last modified, hour file last modified, minute file last modified, and the pathname.  In addition, for each directory whose contents are displayed, the
> total number of 512-byte blocks used by the files in the directory is
> displayed on a line by itself, immediately before the information for the
> files in the directory.  If the file or directory has extended
> attributes, the permissions field printed by the `-l` option is followed by
> a '@' character.  Otherwise, if the file or directory has extended security information (such as an access control list), the permissions field
> printed by the `-l` option is followed by a '+' character.
> …

The `man` command is short for “manual”, and the articles it shows are called “man pages”; try running [`man manpages`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/Manpages/man5/manpages.5.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/5/manpages) to learn even more about them.

Comment: This information is [no longer present in the `ls` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ls.1.html). Where can it be found?

Comment: @DrakeP Running `man ls` is your best option for seeing the documentation specific to the version of macOS that you are running. There’s a bit of info about how to find similar versions online here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/374715/11282

Comment: @DrakeP It's still there. It's because the above man page is for macOS which uses BSD tools and they're completely different from the GNU tools in Linux

Answer (score 4):

The following information is provided:

- permissions
- number of linked hardlinks
- owner of the file
- to which group this file belongs to
- size
- modification/creation date and time
- file/directory name